# Write $\cos(5x)$ as a function of $\cos(x)$, answer with a polynomial.

Tags: trigonometry

> Write $\cos(5x)$ as a function of $\cos(x)$, answer with a polynomial.

$$e^{i\cdot5x} = \cos(5x) + i\sin(5x)$$

$$\cos(5x) + i\sin(5x) = (\cos(x) + i\sin(x))^5$$

and using the binomial theorem I think the answer is the real part of the expansion but I fail to see it.

The answer is $16x^5-20x^3+5x$.

Comment: What is the result of your expansion?

Comment: The real part is = (cos^5(x)-10cos^3(x)sin^2(x)+5sin^4(x)cos(x))

Comment: This is mathematical malpractice. The answer is a polynomial in $\cos(x)$, not in $\x$. Asking for a "polynomial" is misleading, and giving a polynomial in terms of $x$ is just flat wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a given integer $n$,

$$\cos (n+1)t+\cos(n-1)t=2\cos(t)\cos(nt)$$

Here I use the general formula $\cos p+\cos q=2\cos\frac{p+q}2\cos\frac{p-q}2$.

Hence, if $T_n(x)$ is a polynomial such that $T_n(\cos(t))=\cos(nt)$, then

$$T_{n+1}(x)=2xT_n(x)-T_{n-1}(x)$$

With trivially $T_0(x)=1$ and $T_1(x)=x$.

Then

$$T_2(x)=2x^2-1$$
$$T_3(x)=4x^3-3x$$
$$T_4(x)=8x^4-8x^2+1$$
$$T_5(x)=16x^5-20x^3+5x$$

And

$$\cos(5t)=16\cos^5(t)-20\cos^3(t)+5\cos(t)$$

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials

Comment: This works nicely too! Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You have by De Moivre's formula that $$(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^5=\cos(5x)+i\sin(5x)$$

but $$(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^5=\cos^5(x)-10\sin^2(x)\cos^3(x)+5\sin^4(x)\cos(x)$$
$$+i(\sin^5(x)+5\sin(x)\cos^4(x)-10\sin^3(x)\cos^2(x)).$$

Now compare real parts and use the identity $\sin^{2}(x)=1-\cos^2(x).$

You get $$\cos(5x)=16\cos^5(x)-20\cos^3(x)+5\cos(x).$$

Comment: Oh now i get it, thanks!